# Ruby Imap Multipart Fetch

Tags: ruby, email, imap, multipart

I trying use the Ruby IMAP library ("net/imap") to get email. I get messages with html and text plain but I need the text plain only ...

My Code Is ...

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('XXX')

imap.authenticate('LOGIN', 'USER', "PASS") imap.examine('INBOX') 

imap.search(['UNSEEN']).each do |message_id| 
  
  body = imap.fetch(message_id,'BODY[TEXT]')[0].attr['BODY[TEXT]'] 

  puts body 

end
```

Here I get

> --57887f32df9433962df2d01c44487353c74c0f6d2b9721d30fc189fadae2 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
>
> Summary: XXX description: XXX.
>
> --57887f32df9433962df2d01c44487353c74c0f6d2b9721d30fc189fadae2--

But I need just

> Summary: XXX description: XXX.

How could I get it without require "mail"

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off asking for the specific part number in a follow-on `fetch <msgno> body[<partnum>]` imap request.  This returns the actual mime part and not just the body text with the MIME encodings.

Eg, I use the following loop to retreive messages into `mime_parts` (assume `@imap` is your already established imap client):

```
  new_msgs = @imap.uid_search('UNSEEN')
  puts "Found #{new_msgs.size} new messages"
  new_msgs.each do |msg_uid|
    msgs = @imap.uid_fetch(msg_uid, ['BODY', 'FLAGS', 'ENVELOPE'])
    raise "unexpected number of messages, count=#{msgs.size}" if msgs.size > 1
    @imap.uid_store(msg_uid, '+FLAGS', [:Seen]).inspect
    msg = msgs.first
    body = msg.attr['BODY']
    if body.media_type.eql?('MULTIPART')
      mime_parts = []
      body.parts.each.with_index do |part, idx|
        body_part = "BODY[#{idx+1}]"
        fetch_part = @imap.uid_fetch(msg_uid, body_part)
        mime_parts << part.to_h.merge!({content: fetch_part.first.attr[body_part]})
      end
    else
      fetch_text = @imap.uid_fetch(msg_uid, 'BODY[TEXT]')
      mime_parts = [{
          media_type: 'TEXT', subtype: 'PLAIN',
          content: fetch_text.first.attr['BODY[TEXT]']
        }]
    end
  end
```

You can then iterate over your mime_parts and do whatever you please with them.